# Haskell signatures: basics

Tags: haskell

Why this does not work exactly?

```
sum :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> c
sum a b = a + b
```

For sure, the error message is related to the signature but I continue to not understand the reason.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘b’
‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for:
    sum :: forall a b c. (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> c

‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for:
    sum :: forall a b c. (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> c

In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘b’
In the expression: a + b
In an equation for ‘sum’: sum a b = a + b
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `(+)` function has signature:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So that means that the `(+)` function **requires the operands to have the same type**, and the result has the same type as the operands.

Your signature would mean that a programmer can pick any `Num` type as first operand, and any `Num` type as second operand, and then construct *any* type. So it would mean that I could specialize the function into `sum :: Int -> Float -> Char`, but there is no such `(+)` defined.

We *can* make the type more flexible, for instance by using `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`:

```
integralSum :: (Integral i, Integral j, Num c) => i -> j -> c
integralSum x y = fromIntegral x + fromIntegral y
```

Comment: And why if I write the signatures this way: 
sum :: (Num a, Num c) => a -> a -> c
It still does not work?

Comment: That implies you convert between `Num` types.  If you are given a `Num` constraint then all you know how to do is basic arithmetic and convert from an Integer (see `:info Num` in GHCi).  So you can write a `sum` with that signature but the implementation would have to look something like `sum _ _ = fromInteger 42` since you have no way to convert the input `a` types to arbitrary output `c` types.

Comment: @BigMeister: there are no generic ways to convert any num to any num, since you could for instance introduce an *algebraic* num as well.

Answer (score 7):

For a different answer let's try ignoring everything besides the type signature.

```
sum :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> c
```

This says that if I give you a value of some type and all you know is it is an instance of `Num` (the `a` type variable), and I give you a second value which could be a different type but also a `Num` (the `b` type variable), then you know how to give me a value of *any* type I ask for (`c`).

That is,  I'm going to give you `(3%4 :: Rational)` and `(7.99 :: Double)`  could you please give me `val :: Config` which is the configuration structure for my web server?  The expression `sum (3%4) 7.99 :: Config` matches your type signature after all.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the type of the `+` operator. We can do this in `ghci` with the `:t` command:

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Note that both operands and the return value must all have the same type. This is why you get the compiler errors. You are allowing `sum` to take operands of two different types. So you can change your type signature to

```
sum :: (Num a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

If you want to add numbers of different types, you will need additional logic to convert the parameters to the same type before applying the `+` operator.